# The first number I inputted in a textfield to another textfield isn't showing

Tags: java, swing, numbers, jtextfield

I want to input numbers in jTextField1 and have it show in jTextField2 as I'm inputting it in the jTextField1 but the first number I'm inputting in the jTextField1 doesn't show in the jTextField2 unless I input another number but then the last number I input do not show.

This is how the output becomes:

```
jTextField1 = 1 jTextField2 = (blank)
jTextField1 = 12 jTextField2 = 1
jTextField1 = 123 jTextField2 = 12
jTextField1 = 1234 jTextField2 = 123
```

I used this:

```
 private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
    String jj = jTextField1.getText();
    int len = jj.length();
    char jw = evt.getKeyChar();
    
    if (Character.isDigit(jw) || (jw==KeyEvent.VK_BACKSPACE) || (jw==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))
        jTextField1.setEditable(true);
    else
        jTextField1.setEditable(false);
    
    if (evt.getKeyChar()>='0' && evt.getKeyChar()<='9')
    {
        if (len<10)
            jTextField1.setEditable(true);
        else
            jTextField1.setEditable(false);
    } 
    
    jTextField2.setText(jTextField1.getText());
}
```

Comment: You should provide a [mre] for your problem, as it is not clear here how all the other components that have an effect are set up (e.g. what listener are you using and how?).

Comment: Just by guessing, what's happening here is most likely that you are using a `KeyListener`, that sets the text of `jTextField2` by retrieving the text from `jTextField1`. But the issue is then that at the point of time where your `keyPressed` event is processed, the actual content of the `jTextField1` has not been fully updated yet.

Comment: I edited the whole code I used but I'm not sure what listener am I using.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comments, what's likely happening here (you should still provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) is that you are using a `KeyListener` in combination with `keyPressed`, that sets the text of `jTextField2` by retrieving the text from `jTextField1`. But the issue is that at the point of time where your `keyPressed` event is processed, the actual content of the `jTextField1` has not been fully updated yet. Therefore you are retrieving the "old text" via `getText()`.

So omit the `KeyListener` and add a `DocumentListener` to your `JTextField` where you want to retrieve the text from. This will work as this listener is called after the text in your `JTextField` has been updated, so `getText()` will retrieve the correct text. More information on the DocumentListener can be found in the Oracle Tutorial [How to Write a Document Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).

(Using the `keyReleased` method of the `KeyListener` seems to work aswell as an alternative solution, but I found this to be "laggy" when testing.)

Working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> buildGui());
}

private static void buildGui() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(10);

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("TextField 1:");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("TextField 2:");

    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, 2);
    panel.setLayout(layout);
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(label1);
    panel.add(textField1);
    panel.add(label2);
    panel.add(textField2);

    // document listener for textField1
    textField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            modifiedDocument(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            modifiedDocument(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            modifiedDocument(e);
        }

        public void modifiedDocument(DocumentEvent e) {
            textField2.setText(textField1.getText());
        }

    });

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple GUI example for you.  Please note that the layout is not ideal :)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class ExampleGui {

      private JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();

      private JTextField nameTextField = new JTextField();
      private JTextField copyOfNameTextField = new JTextField();


      private JFrame buildFrame(){

          mainFrame.setSize(500, 500);

          nameTextField.setSize(100,100);
          copyOfNameTextField.setSize(100,100);

          mainFrame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, nameTextField);
          mainFrame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, copyOfNameTextField);


          nameTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
              public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                  copyOfNameTextField.setText(nameTextField.getText());
              }
          });

          return mainFrame;
      }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

          ExampleGui exampleGui = new ExampleGui();
          exampleGui.buildFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

The method where you are building your gui components will be where you add your keyListener.

Comment: Thank you for answering but can I ask where exactly do I put this particular code? Do I put it under the private void of the jTextField1 or should it get its own space?